# parsing a file using getline() into a new file, while ignoring duplicate entries

Tags: c++, parsing, vector, io, getline

I'm trying to write a program that prompts a user for a file and its file path and then reads the file. It then takes the text in the file and stores it into a vector after parsing the data and separating it into a few categories  (department, item code, quantity, and cost).

I'm having a few issues knowing how to use getline() correctly, and I'm unsure of a few aspects of it. Overall I'm trying to understand how to assign each element to the appropriate object variable, currently I'm lacking in experience with doing this sort of thing as well as using OOP.

The text contained in the file will look like the following.

```
21 Music 64679-701 487 28.77
22 Outdoors 63739-141 195 83.23
23 Books 0268-1154 976 65.17
```

After I am able to get that portion working correctly I'll be working on checking for duplicates and ignoring any that are found.

main.cpp

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <libgen.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include "Record.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        vector<Record> records; //vector of type Records to hold each "Line" of input file
        string filename;        // File name and path stored as string

        /**
         * Prompts user for the name of input file and stores in string variable filename
         *
         */
        cout << "please enter the name of your file with file path:" << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        ifstream ifs { filename.c_str() };
        if (!ifs) {
            cerr << " Can't open file " << filename << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        string path = filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of("\\/"));
        string file = filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("\\/") + 1,
                filename.length());
        if (path.compare(file) == 0) {
            path == "";
        }
        //test for file and file path

        cout << "Path portion of " << filename << " is " << path << endl; //
        cout << "File portion of " << filename << " is " << file << endl; // path + "new_" + file + ".cvs", make new file with new path

        /**
         * Put each line of input file in to the records vector
         */

        string line; //strings for each parameter of the vector object


        while (getline(ifs, line)) {

            Record newRecord(line);

//Here is where I'm having trouble with using get line to parse and store the information. 
//It is incorrect at the moment, and I have the start of how I think I should be going about it.


// check if this record exists in the vector, if not add, else ignore

            records.push_back(newRecord);

        }
        ifs.close(); //closes the stream

        return 0;
    }
```

Record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H_
#define RECORD_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Record {
public:

    //Constructor
    Record(std::string s); //pass this string to our Record class

    //De-constructor
    virtual ~Record();

    //overloaded "==" and "<" comparison operators

    friend bool operator ==(const Record &a, const Record &b);

    //friend bool operator <(const Record &a, const Record &b);  //Do not need at this time.

    //Overloaded "<<" operator

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const Record&);


private:
        std::string department;
        std::string item_code;
        int quantity;
        double cost;

};

#endif /* RECORD_H_ */
```

Record.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "Record.h"

using namespace std;

Record::Record(string s) {

    /**
     * Create a string stream from 's' and use getline(stringStream, line, ",") to
     * read each element from the string using the "," as the delimiter. Assign
     * each element to the appropriate object variable
     */
     //getline(s, line.cost, line.department, line.item_code, line.quantity, ",");
}

Record::~Record() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

//overloaded "==" and "<" comparison operators

bool operator ==(const Record &lhs, const Record &rhs){
    return (lhs.cost == rhs.cost && lhs.department == rhs.department &&
            lhs.item_code == rhs.item_code && lhs.quantity == rhs.quantity);
}

/**bool operator <(const Record &a, const Record &b){ //do not need at this time

}
**/

//Overloaded "<<" operator
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Record& r){
    os << r.department << ',' << r.item_code << ',' <<  r.quantity << ',' << r.cost;
    return os;

}
```

Comment: IMHO, you should overload `operator>>` for your `Record` as well.

Comment: You are giving getline a delimiter of comma, but your text file doesn't contain any commas.  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: If you want no duplicates maybe use a set instead of a vector?

Comment: I'm thinking I'm going to use the Overloaded <<  operator and that will be placing the ',' in its output stream which I'll be using getline on.